# Why does my test winforms application seem to run sequencially?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, vmware, windows-server-2012

I have a number of VMWare Server 2012 instances of very high specification (32 CPU's) but I seem to have performance issues when running certain applications.

So, I created a .Net winforms EXE that simply loops until a counter is reached:

```
            do
            {
              mystring = counter++.ToString();  
            } while (counter != loops);
```

I found on my production server, I can run 1.2M loops in 1 minute. However, when I run multiple instances of the executable, it simply takes twice as long.

Needless to say, the more instances I run, the longer it takes. ie. 10 insances takes around 11 minutes.

When I look at CPU usage: 
    1 instance = 6%
   10 instances = 0.5% each

So, my question is.. why is the server seem to be running this sequencially, rather than in parallel?? Is it a .Net issue? A server configuration issue? A VMware issue?

Comment: The server doesn't run anything sequentially. Every process has its own threads and the OS schedules *threads* for execution. If two threads end up scheduled on the same core, they'll have to wait each other. Since you have a *server*, it's highly likely that desktops have lower priority than services and may even be restricted to a subset of the cores

Comment: On the other hand, your loop doesn't just increment a value, it generates a temporary string at each iteration. That means, 1.2M temporary objects that require garbage collection in a minute. I suspect memory usage goes up as the loop runs too. The performance you see is probably just garbage collection, not the loop itself. 1.2M in one minute is only 20K iterations per second

Comment: @panagiotis Thanks for the reply. Performance monitor show that 4 cores per app are being used, across multiple CPU's but does not seem to use all CPU's available. How can I check if my UI apps are restricted to to a subset of cores.  Incidentally, 'mystring' is declared outside the loop, so it is not generting a new string each time memory usage is constant.

Comment: strings are immutable. Its making a new string. Please, go back to measuring and accept that your current result is junk.

Comment: @Quibblesome I don't see how that is relevant to the problem. Each instance of the application is creating the same workload for the processors. Yet that workload is not distributed evenly across all available resources. 50% of the available CPU's remain idle. Removing the toString altogether produces the same results in terms of the resource allocation.

Comment: I've already told you that this code is more than likely being run on possibly a single thread on a single core because its a WinForm app that is poorly written. What more do you want? You have the attention of a Windows developer with decades of experience and you're bickering in trying to protect your terrible measurement.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's a good way to test it. 
Basically you're testing the user interface and its not insane to conceive that the user interface is only being served by one core.

WinForm apps (as well as things that derive from it like WPF) specficially handle the UI on one primary UI thread, if they try to muck around with the UI on other threads, race-conditions occur which used to result in random lock-ups and freezes but today just throw exceptions (this is better). You can use multi-threading in a WinForm app (doesn't look like you are) but you can't touch the visual components on those threads. ALL visual component events (click, mouse hover, etc) will be handled on the UI thread.

Console apps would probably give you a clearer read. Better would be going to find a tool that someone else has made because there's tons of gotchas in terms of measuring performance and you might be falling foul of those.

For reference: running to conclusions that something is wrong off the basis of tests like this is not good (e.g. in VMWare, the servers or Windows), if you were a colleague, I'd think less of you. Be more cautious in such bold assertions and believe the issue is with your test *first* and *foremost*. That's the best mindset *always* when trying to measure performance.
After you've been hitting the same wall for maybe like a week or months, that's when you might start to question software products that have *huge* user bases and highly sophisticated release processes and QA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I was assuming a configuration issue is when I run the same tests on my local hardware the problem is not as evident. It takes 2.5minutes to run 1 but only 8 minutes to run 10, which is faster than the much more powerful servers.

Comment: how are you timing these? You should be using System.Diagnostics.StopWatch and then Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds

Comment: I simply run the application and see how long it takes to finish. My assumption being that if 1 set of hardware takes 1 minute, running the same application twice should still only take just over 1 minute as there are plenty of resources to cope with running 2 simple loops at the same time.

Comment: Ye, don't do that. You're a human, you're messy, you're wrong. Get computers to do the timings and never, ever, ever, trust yourself. All your assumptions will be proved to be wrong. For the most part performance testing is about questioning _yourself_.  
I would suggest doing a bit more research. Try heading over to irc.freenode.net and find a room with sysadmins and ask them. Alternatively repost the question "how to test this" on here.

Comment: Well I am not physically timing it myself, with a stopwatch. The app shows start time and end time so how can it be wrong?

Comment: You're a human, you are wrong. You write the code, the code is wrong. All these things are wrong and performance testing is mostly about finding truth in all the lies that you'll tell. Manually timing it via an external program is noise that you don't want. You want to measure lots and throw away most of your results. It sounds to me like you've made few, noisy measurements and have jumped straight to conclusions. Go back to measuring. Anyway we've identified a key issue, don't use a WinForm app to measure.

Comment: @user10960824 1.2M iterations per minute is glacially slow. Only 20K iterations per second. On the other hand you're creating 1.2M temporary strings that have to be garbage collected. I suspect what you time is the garbage collector, not the loop at all

Comment: We should also consider testing something that is not actually almost a no-op as that "no-op" itself is lossy (as per Panagiotis's comment). Find whatever sort of operation it is that you're going to be doing on these machines and actually time that.

Comment: What we are doing on these machines is running a winforms (MS Dynamics) app that is not performing as expected. So, my test winforms app was to see how the box allocates resources when running winforms apps, seemed the sensible thing to test with to see if it is a genral issue with configuration of the box, or an issue with the microsoft application.

Comment: this is what I suspected. You have an axe to grind and you've allowed it to colour your attempts to measure. The Dynamics we use is web based and its extension is purely plugin based afaik so idk what winform has to do with that, some config or import tool maybe? Perhaps it would be better to approach this problem from the Dynamics side and ask a question specifically about the operation you're attempting to perform?

Comment: I am trying to find out why this app is not performing as expected. The version we use is 100% winforms desktop application. Nothing to do with web whatsoever. The operations it performs do not utilise the resources as expected.

Comment: and I suspect you have already reached a conclusion and are collecting evidence to support it. This is the wrong mindset and illustrates some of the challenges you are facing. If you cared about the app performing as expected you'd be testing the app and not making bizarre WinForm applications that don't prove anything.

Comment: If it is a WinForm app that you develop then you should return to the sources and benchmark it. If its calls to Dynamics that are problematic then you should capture those (e.g. Fiddler)

Comment: I don't think you understand... The application we have trouble with is 100% winforms. We don't make any 'calls' to it. We have already tested and benchmarked the troublesome areas of the and get crappy results with poor allocation of resources. My test winforms app also has the same issues where resources are not utilised. So... back to my original question... what might be causing this??? I have no idea, and clearly...neither do you, you just keep adding pointless comments that do not even relate to the question or my particular issue.

Comment: Like I've already stated multiple times if you only use the UI thread in a WinForm application you will not be able to obtain usage of all the cores on the machine.

Comment: If you want to see if your host environment is somehow inconsistent with your local environment in terms of resource usage I would consider creating a CONSOLE APPLICATION instead.

Comment: give it a bunch of work and use async/await and TPL (Task.WaitAll()) to process multiple operations at the same time as that allows the OS to make better smarter choices about resource allocation.